# Can't connect to postgresql server after moving database files

Tags: postgresql, debian, postgresql-9.4

I want to move my postgresql databases to an external hard drive (HDD 2TB USB 3.0). I copied the whole directory:

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/
```

to the external drive, preserving permissions, with a command (ran by the user postgres):

```
$ rsync -aHAX /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/* new_dir_path
```

First run of this command was interrupted, but in the second attempt I copied everything (basically one database of size 800 GB). In the file

```
/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

I changed the line

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main'
```

to point to the new location. I restarted the postgresql service, and when from the user postgres I run the command `psql`, I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I didn't change any other settings. There is no pidfile 'postmaster.pid' in the new location (or in the old one). When I run a command

```
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres --single -D /etc/postgresql/9.4/main -P -d 1
```

I get

```
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-1] DEBUG:  mmap with MAP_HUGETLB failed, huge pages disabled: Cannot allocate memory
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-2] NOTICE:  database system was shut down at 2017-03-16 20:01:23 CET
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-3] DEBUG:  checkpoint record is at 647/4041B3A0
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-4] DEBUG:  redo record is at 647/4041B3A0; shutdown TRUE
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-5] DEBUG:  next transaction ID: 1/414989450; next OID: 112553
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-6] DEBUG:  next MultiXactId: 485048384; next MultiXactOffset: 1214064579
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-7] DEBUG:  oldest unfrozen transaction ID: 259446705, in database 12141
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-8] DEBUG:  oldest MultiXactId: 476142442, in database 12141
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-9] DEBUG:  transaction ID wrap limit is 2406930352, limited by database with OID 12141
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-10] DEBUG:  MultiXactId wrap limit is 2623626089, limited by database with OID 12141
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-11] DEBUG:  starting up replication slots
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-12] DEBUG:  oldest MultiXactId member is at offset 1191132700
2017-03-16 20:47:39 CET [2314-13] DEBUG:  MultiXact member stop limit is now 1191060352 based on MultiXact 476142442

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.4.9
backend>
```

but I don't now how to understand this output. When I revert the changes in the `postgresql.conf` file, everything works fine. Interestingly, few months ago I moved the database in the same way, but to the local directory, and it worked.
I use postgresql-9.4 and debian-jessie.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

Content of the log file:

```
$ cat /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
2017-03-14 17:07:16 CET [13822-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2017-03-14 17:07:16 CET [13822-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2017-03-14 17:07:16 CET [13827-3] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2017-03-14 17:07:16 CET [13824-1] LOG:  shutting down
2017-03-14 17:07:16 CET [13824-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: how did you start the db?.. `pg_ctl` or service?

Comment: service, `sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: probaby unix_socket_directory is misconfigured?.. if you gave listen_address=* in conf, try `psql -p 5432`

Comment: Hi @Gwidryj please update your question with the log output (in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql***.log` and let me know when its done so I can review them

Comment: There are inbuilt methods to deal with this. You could take a dump of the original database. Initialise a new DB in the location and restore to it. Then delete your old set up.

Comment: @VaoTsun in my conf file `unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'`, I didn't change it. Switch `-p 5432` is redundant and didn't help, as this is a default port.

Comment: @Gab I updated my question. What's strange, content of the log file doesn't change on `sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: @Mokadillion I think that taking a dump of a 800GB database is not the best approach, I don't even have enough space on the old disk to save it, but thanks for hint

Comment: @Gwidryj maybe the logs are configured to be saved elsewhere. Can you check what is in `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: @Gab unfortunately that's not the case. I didn't change the default location. I have just tried to start the server with `data_directory` pointing to the old directory and everything worked and new logs were saved. Then, I change the data dir again to the new dir (which is an exact copy of the old one) and service says it's working, but I get no logs and psql cannot find the server.

Comment: If the PostgreSQL version did not change and you properly shut off Postgres before copying the files I am not sure what could explain what's happening. You might want to go with @Gwidryj advice and do a dump/restore or set up replication and make the slave a master when its catches up. I understand you don't have enough space on the primary HD but you can always mount the secondary hard drive and make it the pg_dump or slave destination. That will work. If I were in your situation with no logical explanation for the issue you are encountering I would take that approach. Hope it helps